# Postgres limit is showing wrong number of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, limit

I've created a query in Postgres which is limiting the number of results but for some reason, my limit clause is showing one less result that I ask for. Here is the query:

```
select articles.title, articles.slug, count.views 
from articles, 
     (select path, count(path) as views 
      from log 
      where status = '200 OK' 
         and path != '/' 
      group by path 
      order by views desc limit 3
 ) count 
 WHERE articles.slug LIKE LTRIM(count.path, '/article/');
```

but when I run it, I only get the first 2 rows. If I change the 3 to 4, I get the first 3 rows and so on. Any suggestions?

Comment: The rows chosen in the subquery are filtered out by the `where` clause.

Comment: Why are you using a `LIKE` if you are not using a wildcard? That is essentially the same as an inner join using `articles.slug = LTRIM(count.path, '/article/');`

Comment: When I remove the limit, all 6 relevant rows are displayed and if I use limit 3 offset 1 in returns the top 3 rows as requested so I believe the Gordon's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

When I remove the limit, all 6 relevant rows are displayed and if I use limit 3 offset 1 in returns the top 3 rows as requested so I believe the Gordon's answer is correct. – Gerry de Caires